# Non-uniqueness of (Galerkin) approximations and convergent subsequences without the axiom of choice?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sequences-and-series, axiom-of-choice

Suppose I have an equation in some reflexive separable Banach space $X$:
$$Au=f$$
for given data $f \in X^*$ and $A\colon X \to X^*$ a pseudo-monotone operator. Existence can be proved via Galerkin approximations where one takes a finite dimensional subspace $X_n \subset X$ for each $n$ and considers
$$\langle Au_n, \varphi_j \rangle = \langle f, \varphi_j\rangle \quad\forall j=1,...,n$$
where $\{\varphi_j\}_{j=1}^n$ is a basis for $X_n$ and $u_n$ is supposed to lie in the span of this basis. The $X_n$ are supposed to approximate $X$.

Then one derives a uniform estimate like $\lVert u_n \rVert_X \leq C$ and passes to the limit using weak compactness. My question is the following.

Typically there is no uniqueness of solutions for the equation, nor for the Galerkin approximations. Showing that the Galerkin approximations $u_n$ exist is done by applying the lemma of acute angle and the proof is not constructive. This means that $u_n$ is not unique and there may be uncountable many solutions for each $n$ -- unless something is ruling it out that I'm missing.

In this case, how can we choose a sequence and then apply Banach--Alagolu to that sequence without using the axiom of choice to select an element for each $n$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3613810/non-uniqueness-of-galerkin-approximations-and-convergent-subsequences-without, do not cross-post.

Comment: The do-not-cross-post will be left as a reminder to others to perhaps check the other site to see whether an answer has appeared there, before committing time to answering it here. This is the usual way things are done around here.